# Make multiple NSUserNotifications (and their action) buttons perform separate actions

Tags: swift, nsusernotification, nsusernotificationcenter

I've been learning Swift at my own pace, and I've dived into notification buttons, and making them do things, after learning how to make NSUserNotifications.

I know how to make a single notification's action button perform an action by using the below in AppDelegate.swift

```
func userNotificationCenter(center: NSUserNotificationCenter, didActivateNotification notification: NSUserNotification) 
{
  print("You clicked the notification button!")
}
```

The question is, how do I make a second one do the same? I've searched high and low for an easy-to-understand answer here on SO, reddit, and via numerous Swift tutorial websites before I asked this question, as while delegates and overriding are no problem for me in C#, and I get the concept, I'm completely at a loss in Swift how to do this.

**Thought Process**

Because `didActivateNotification notification: NSUserNotification`" in `AppDelegate.swift` contained the identifier "notification", which was also the identifier for my first NSUserNotification object in my ViewController class, if I declared `userNotificationCenter()` again, and changed "didActivateNotification notification: NSUserNotification" to "didActivateNotification notif: NSUserNotification", for my second NSUserNotification object with the identifier 'notif', it should execute the relevant actions for my second notification's action button, which was printing a slightly different message to the console, right?

Needless to say, it didn't work.

**What I did in terms of UI**

I had two buttons, each of which generated a notification with different text, and action buttons which would (***supposedly***) do different things.

**Wrapping up**

So, what would I need to do to have two (or more) notifications' action buttons perform their respective actions?

Any help is very gratefully received, and thanked for in advanced.

Comment: Has anyone not faced this issue before?